# XCode: added cocoa pods, want to include added workspace in source control/bitbucket

Tags: xcode, git, workspace

Mac: 
I added cocoa pods. Got it all installed correctly after some confusion.

XCode: 
I have a project already under source control & linked to bitbucket.
I added a 'pod' for AFNetworking to , which added a 'Pods' project and wrapped everything in a workspace, which I now open instead of the project.
However, the repository doesn't seem to have picked this up. It seems to be 'project centered', and I want everything in source control that should/needs to be there to be all there.

How do I add the workspace, or change the repository's scope to 'zoom-out' and go from workspace down?

Comment: ok, I ran 'git init' from the project/workspace directory, then committed again and it added the workspace and a few supporting files it seemed. But still not the 'Pods' folder. Is it supposed too?

Comment: The repo's "scope" depends on where the .git folder is. If you ran git init again, you may now have a nested repo if you had one already in a sub directory. Also, you have to manually add the files that you want git to track, so git isn't "supposed" to add any files unless you tell it to. You also ought to double check your .gitignore files, including a possible ~/.gitignore_global to see if you're ignoring the Pods folder.

Comment: ok yes, I ran git init last night and it seems to have it all showing now. Appreciate it